# Date.getTime() is taking to much time to process when in spanish

Tags: android, date, android-sdk-2.3, gettime

I am trying to convert `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZZ"` to unix time in my app.
This is my code:

```
public String getCreatedAt() {
    String formattedCreatedAt = twitterCreatedAt.replace(":", "");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZZ");
    try {
        formattedCreatedAt = Long.toString(dateFormat.parse(formattedCreatedAt).getTime());
        formattedCreatedAt = formattedCreatedAt.substring(0, formattedCreatedAt.length() - 3);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return "0";
    }
    return formattedCreatedAt;

}
```

My (weird) problem is that when the device is in english all is OK but when I am changing the device language to spanish in galaxy s2 with android 2.3.6 the line of code `formattedCreatedAt = Long.toString(dateFormat.parse(formattedCreatedAt).getTime());`  is taking a lot more time to process.  Why could it be? Thanks!

This is the part that is taking the long time:

```
dateFormat.parse(formattedCreatedAt);
```

Comment: Could you divide this line in many lines like parse the string first, then get call getTime and use Long's toString method in last and see what takes time ?

Comment: I added the specific command that is taking the long time. its the "parse" commend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [site](http://andmob.wikidot.com/faq-simpletimeformat) :

> SimpleDateFormat, the first time you try parsing (or, presumably,
>   formatting) a date, will load in all the timezone data for your
>   locale. This will take 2-3 seconds. It is hoped that this will be
>   fixed in some future edition of Android.
>
> In the interim, consider using AsyncTask to "warm up" SimpleDateFormat
>   in your process before you need it. Just parse some date in the
>   AsyncTask doInBackground() to get it to load the timezones sometime
>   when it will not impact the user so much. Once initialized in your
>   process, SimpleDateFormat will run quickly until your process is
>   terminated.

There is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3147) and you can find an explanation :

> This is due to the lazy initialization of the timezone zone strings.
>   Only the first call will take this long. If the SimpleDateFormat is
>   used again afterwards it's loaded from cache and shouldn't take that
>   long anymore.
>
> Before this was changed it was done when the class was loaded and thus
>   the start of an activity took those 2-3 seconds longer. This had a
>   much worse impact on the user experience than if it takes those
>   seconds when it's actually used the first time. The problem is that
>   there's no way right now to circumvent this issue due to the design of
>   the SimpleDateFormat api. Only faster phones might fix this by just
>   taking less time to collect those strings.
>
> The caching happens in the DateFormatSymbols that SimpleDateFormat is
>   using. By reusing that instance it's possible to only have to load the
>   stings once (for the same loale). You could also create that Instance
>   in a thread at the startup of the activity so that it's already cached
>   once it's used. To init the strings just call .hashCode() which does
>   force initialize the cache. A bit faster but less simple would be to
>   serialize the instance. This also forces the cache to be initialized.

Since this happens only the first time your function is called (due to the initialization of the timezone strings), I would recommend (as they said) to use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to "pre-load" the `SimpleDateFormat`. I think it will fix your problem.